# Creating OnCompletionListener in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-mediaplayer

I am a Java/Andriod programmer new to Kotlin and Jetpack Compose. I am creating a simple sound-board app with three buttons that will play a unique sound when pressed.  All is going well, but I am struggling with creating the OnCompletionListener for the Mediaplayer instances (so I can release resources and change the button on the UI)

Within my button Composable I create the instance of the Mediaplayer

```
`val mediaPlayer:MediaPlayer by remember {
    mutableStateOf(MediaPlayer.create(context,soundID))
}`
```

which works great in the OnClick of the Image composable:

```
        Image (
            painter = painterResource(id = (imageID)),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(250.dp)
                .aspectRatio(16f / 9f)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(cornerDiameter.dp))
                .border(
                    BorderStroke(4.dp, Color.Yellow),
                    RoundedCornerShape(cornerDiameter.dp)
                )
                .clickable(
                    enabled = true,
                    onClick = {
                        if (isPlaying) {
                            println("STOPPING player")
                            mediaPlayer.pause()
                            isPlaying = false

                        } else {
                            println("starting player")
                            mediaPlayer.start()
                            isPlaying = true
                        }
                    }
                )
             )
```

When the respective audio is done playing I want to call a routine to clean up and update the UI.  When I create the onCompletionLIstener I send it the instance of the MediaPlayer:

```
   val onCompletionListener = 
    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(trackDone(mediaPlayer))
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener)
```

which expects the function trackDone to be `(MediaPlayer!) → Unit`, which it auto creates:

```
fun trackDone(mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer): (MediaPlayer) -> Unit {

    if(mediaPlayer != null)
    {
        mediaPlayer!!.stop()
        mediaPlayer!!.release()

    }
}
```

However, I now get an error for trackDone saying `"A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')"`.  But I can't figure out what type of return I can provide to satisfy this.  Returning mediaPlayer does not work.

Any help is appreciated. I hope I have given enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler expects `trackDone` to return a `lambda` that accepts a `MediaPlayer` and returns nothing. I'm not sure what you want to accomplish with this function signature but the code below will fix the compile error.

```
fun trackDone(mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer): (MediaPlayer) -> Unit {

    if(mediaPlayer != null)
    {
        mediaPlayer!!.stop()
        mediaPlayer!!.release()
    }

    return {}
}
```

I assume this is not exactly your intention and instead you want some `callback` from this function.

First, please clean it up, you don't need to check for `nullability` and you don't need to shout `!!` in your code, because the function already expects a **non-nullable** `MediaPlayer` argument.

Next, simply add an additional function type parameter that will be used as a `callback` inside `trackDone`.

Putting them all together, your `trackDone` function should look like this

```
fun trackDone(mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer, onComplete : (MediaPlayer) -> Unit)  {

    // remove unnecessary nullability checking
    mediaPlayer.stop()
    mediaPlayer.release()
    
    
    // on complete callback
    onComplete(mediaPlayer)
}
```

or if you don't want to return the `MediaPlayer` instance then this,

```
fun trackDone(mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer, onComplete : () -> Unit)  {

    // remove unnecessary nullability checking
    mediaPlayer.stop()
    mediaPlayer.release()
    
    
    // on complete callback
    onComplete()
}
```

and this is how it would be **used** 'ideally'.

```
fun someFunction() {

    val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer
    
    ...
    ...
    ...
    
    trackDone(mediaPlayer) { stoppedMediaPlayer ->
        // DONE
    }

    // or

    trackDone(mediaPlayer) {
        // DONE
    }
}
```

Now I have no idea if this would "work" for a "completeListener" callback like you want to achieve, but the "fix" will surely compile.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the input.  Your response has helped me in several ways, particularly in my understanding of the structure.  Yes, I needed to do some clean up.    As you mentioned, you would think I would want some sort of callback, but the onCompletionLIstener line would not accept anything with a callback - hence some of my issues.   In the end I am going to have to structure things differently (and clean up my MVVM knowledge).  Thanks again (sorry or delay)